# Displaying child categories indefinitely with PHP

Tags: php

I don't know if this is possible with the current DB schema, but here goes. I have main categories, these are simply marked with a boolean value in the DB. Then there is a comma-delimited list of subcategories.

For example:

```
MainCat1
    SubCat1
        SubCat2
        SubCat2-1
            Subcat3
```

So in MainCat1's subcategory field there would simply be "SubCat1" and in SubCat1's subcategory field there would be "SubCat2, SubCat2-1" and so forth.

I hope that makes sense! I don't mind how you show it, they will eventually be nested lists.

DB Schema:

```
id        |maincat  |       subcats     |
---+---------+--------------------------+
MainCat1  |    1    |SubCat1            |
SubCat1   |    0    |SubCat2, SubCat2-1 |
SubCat2   |    0    |                   |
SubCat2-1 |    0    |SubCat3            |
SubCat3   |    0    |                   |
```

Comment: What does your DB schema look like?

Comment: I did try to explain it above, just below the code block. Does that not make sense?

Comment: @Ashley, what you described isn't a database schema. Please add more details.

Comment: That's the wrong way round. You should define the parent node in each child, not a comma separated list of child nodes in the parent.

Comment: Added schema, is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create sublevels:

```
MainCat1             // sublevel = 0
    SubCat1          // sublevel = 1
        SubCat2      // sublevel = 2
        SubCat2-1    // sublevel = 2
            Subcat3  // sublevel = 3
```

You can use arraykeys to set the sublevel:

```
$menu[0][0] = 'MainCat1';
$menu[1][0] = 'SubCat1';
$menu[2][0] = 'SubCat2';
$menu[2][1] = 'SubCat2-1';
$menu[3][0] = 'Subcat3';
```